# Why is Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGED not honoured?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

I try to start a transaction-less JMS session using `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` as acknowledge mode.

Unfortunatly, when I start my session, the acknowledge mode is always `Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`. Why ?

I'm connecting from a remote glassfish client to a glassfish server (using standard embedded OpenMQ broker). Session initialization code is

```
    boolean transacted = false;
    int acknowledgeMode = Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE;
    session = getConnection().createSession(transacted, acknowledgeMode);
    if(transacted!=session.getTransacted())
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("seems like the broker doesn't want us to use untransacted connection");
    if(acknowledgeMode!=session.getAcknowledgeMode())
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("seems like the broker doesn't want us to use Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE");
```

**[EDIT 1]**

Session is obtained from a Connection/ConnectionFactory pair in which the connectionFactory is looked up using JNDI :

```
connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) getContext().lookup(JMSConstants.CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAME);
```

So I may indeed use default settings from the remote connection factory, [as @raffian suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277018/why-is-session-client-acknowledged-not-honoured?noredirect=1#comment28552179_19277018)

Comment: Are you looking up a remote connection factory to obtain the connection? If so, check the settings on the factory. Different vendors provide default values for various connection and session settings,

Comment: @raffian edited to give you more infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Testing is doubting ? Or not ?

So, to investigate that, I created a unit test in which I create a session then check the values of `getTransacted()` and `getAcknowledgeMode()`.

This test obviously confirmed the question I asked upper, that's to say typing `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`results into a JMS session configured with `Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` ... What ?

Yeah, I too was completely stunned.

## Here be dragons

So I did what you all should do when playing with Glassfish. I installed the latest version of [Jadclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jadclipse-eclipse-4x#.UlafgkDD7PU) and restarted my test, debugging all I could.

Creating `ConnectionFactory` seemed OK

Creating `Connection` also seemed OK

But creating Session started with that very code (reproduced from my Jadclipse session in `com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ConnectionAdapter` - Take a look at [`ConnectionAdapter#createSession`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.mq/jms/4.5.2/com/sun/messaging/jms/ra/ConnectionAdapter.java#ConnectionAdapter.createSession%28boolean,int%29)).

```
 if (ResourceAdapter._isFixCR6760301())
 {
   localXASessionImpl = (XASessionImpl)this.xac.createSession(overrideTransacted(paramBoolean), overrideAcknowledgeMode(paramInt), (this.inACC) ? null : this.mc);
 }
 else {
   localXASessionImpl = (XASessionImpl)this.xac.createSession((this.mc.xaTransactionStarted()) ? true : paramBoolean, paramInt, (this.inACC) ? null : this.mc);
 }
```

So obviously my acknowledge mode is rewritten by the grace of a call to [`ConnectionAdapter#overrideAcknowledgeMode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.mq/jms/4.5.2/com/sun/messaging/jms/ra/ConnectionAdapter.java#ConnectionAdapter.overrideAcknowledgeMode%28int%29). Hopefully, the code in grepCode has this very informative comment that really make my day

```
        // EJB spec section 13.3.5 "Use of JMS APIs in Transactions" says
        // "The Bean Provider should not use the JMS acknowledge method either within a transaction 
        // or within an unspecified transaction context. Message acknowledgment in an unspecified 
        // transaction context is handled by the container." 
        // 
        // The same restriction applies in web container: JavaEE Spec: "EE.6.7 Java Message Service (JMS) 1.1 Requirements" says
        // "In general, the behavior of a JMS provider should be the same in both the EJB container and the web container.
        // The EJB specification describes restrictions on the use of JMS in an EJB container, 
        // as well as the interaction of JMS with transactions in an EJB container. 
        // Applications running in the web container should follow the same restrictions.
```

But, unfortunatly, I run my Glassfish client in a kinda weird mode (not exactly inACC, but very similar to it).

So, what can I do ?

## Ride the dragon

Oh, for sure, I could take a look at the infamous bug mentionned upper : [CR6760301](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=d305913bce2f44f72840d2a22ba3?bug_id=6760301) .. mmh, it seems that in fact, nope, I can't (beside, notice of which high quality is the FAQ provided by oracle ...).

So only solution remaining is ..., yeah, for sore, to insert before session creation a little of staticness

```
static {
    /*
     * Want to know why ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19277018/15619 this is why
     */
    System.setProperty("imq.jmsra.fixCR6760301", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
}
```